# Dynamic addition of fields to a django form through user action

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I'm working with django and want to give the user the option to input an arbitrary number of strings into the form and then save this to a database.

What it actually is, is a setup page for a teacher to create a new homework exercise for a student, and if the submission is selected as electronic, the teacher then needs to specify the required filenames + extensions that need to be submitted. So by default only one char field is visible when electronic submission is selected, but I would like a little plus button  next to it to display a new char field below where the teacher can enter a second required filename to be submitted. And another click to add 3rd and so on.

Is this possible and how could i go abut doing this?
I could use a TextField and split by new lines, but it wouldn't look as good as dynamic char fields. And the problem with dynamic adding fields to from when rendered is I don't know the number until after its rendered and teacher selects electronic AND clicks the plus button some unknown number of times.

Comment: This might be a good fit for writing some JavaScript. You can easily update your client-side HTML that way.

Comment: Display sperate text fields just for display, then when they submit, move contents into a hidden django textfield with JS and send it back to view through that. Thats the way im gonna go about it, however was just wandering if people ever had a similar problem :)